# Get time as a string from PHP does not work

Tags: php, objective-c, nsurlconnection

because i don't want to use the NSDATE function of Xcode, i tried to override it with a php script...i found the solution here but it does not work or i can't get it to work.

this is the code:

```
 - (NSDate *) CurrentDate
 {
     if ([self hasInternetConnectivity]) // this tests Internet connectivity based off Apple's Reachability sample code
     { 
         NSURL * scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://<yoursite>.com/<the 2 line php script>.php"];
         NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: scriptUrl];

         if (data! = nil) {
              NSString * tempString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: [data bytes]];
              NSDate * currDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: [tempString doubleValue]];
              NSLog (@"String returned from the site is:% @ and date is:% @", tempString, [currDate description]);
              return currDate;
         } else {
              NSLog (@ "nsdata download failed");
              return [NSDate date];
         }
    } else {
        NSLog (@ "InternetConnectivity failed");
        return [NSDate date];
    }
}
```

Whatever i do it returns errors as in hasInternetConnectivity does not exist in @interface etc..

i just pasted the code into the NAME.m file but it does not want to work..

what i am trying is to get the requested date (php time should return something like 20:10:40 ) in a text field.

its just a string...when someone pushes the button it should get the server time and put it in the text field...

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: It seems that `hasInternetConnectivity` does not exists in your `@interface` ...

Comment: i am getting: no visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'hasInternetConnectivity'

Comment: copy the implementation of hasInternetConnectivity from where you've got the code above

Comment: this was the only "code" that was given... nothing more

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what i did, it works and it leaks a bit but don't worry about it its too small:

```
    NSURL * scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.YOURWEBSITE.com/TIME.php"];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: scriptUrl];
    serverTime = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"servertime is: %@",servertime);
```

this is a example of the phpfile to keep it simple:

```
<?php
$servertime = date("H:i:s");
$string = (string) $servertime;
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: "..it leaks a bit but don't worry about it..", no you should worry about it, when doing your code there should be no leaks, any kind of leak is bad. Not good coding if there is leaks in your code. Its not even hard to resolve the leak in your code.

Comment: @Popeye maybe if you know better you could answer the question

Comment: if your answer works for you then good I was just saying if its got a leak in it then just sort it out  it not a huge issue to sort it but adding comments like the one above will just get comments like this. If you are using `ARC` then there is no leaks but I assume you aren't because of the comment so just add your releases not the comment. This would be one of the those answers to accept if it works for you to improve your score. I was only trying to give constructive advice not trying to offend. Having a good score will help on questions in the future.